# Can you have a Magical Accurate Orb +1?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Can you have a Magical Accurate Orb +1 ?

And what would it's attack plus be ?

The wizard has to take the Superior Implement Training feat [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2624)] and select Orb as the implement. They can then buy the superior implement Accurate Orb from Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium p.40, and use the Accurate property for a +1 to implement attacks.

So could they then enchant it to a Magical Accurate Orb +1 with a total +2 to implement attacks ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, the bonuses stack.**

While the +1 bonus form a +1 magic implement is an **enhancement** bonus, the +1 bonus for the Accurate property of superior implements is **untyped**, so it can stack with other bonuses.

Superior Implement Training make you competent in only one type of superior implement. An [Accurate Orb](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3517)<sup>DDI</sup> and a [Crystal Orb](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3518)<sup>DDI</sup>, for example, are two different types of superior implements and mastering both requires taking the feat twice.